# p4 interchanges showing integrated changelists

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

My team is using a bash script that runs `p4 interchanges -S $stream` in order to determine which task streams still need to be copied up to their parents.

In the case of a stream that has two changelists where one undoes the other (where the cumulative diff is empty), the script is not saying that all revisions are already integrated, despite the stream having already been copied up to its parent.

Is there a way to make `p4 interchanges` recognize that the empty diffs do not need integration, or is there another p4 command we could be using here?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you undid the changelist.  If you used the `p4 undo` command, then `p4 integrate` (and by extension `p4 interchanges`) is able to recognize the relationship between those revisions by following the integration records created by `p4 undo`.  If you undid it with a manual edit, then each revision looks like a new edit from the metadata perspective (which is all that `integrate/interchanges` considers -- actual file content inspection is delegated to `resolve`).

Here's an example file that (I think) demonstrates the situation you're talking about with an undone change, such that the cumulative effect is no diff:

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 filelog -i bar
//stream/test2/undo/bar
... #3 change 250 integrate on 2021/06/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'undo'
... ... undid //stream/test2/undo/bar#2
... #2 change 249 edit on 2021/06/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'foo'
... ... undone by //stream/test2/undo/bar#3
... #1 change 248 branch on 2021/06/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'foo'
... ... branch from //stream/test2/undo/foo#1
//stream/test2/undo/foo
... #1 change 236 add on 2021/01/28 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'add foo'
... ... branch into //stream/test2/undo/bar#1
```

As you can see, `integrate` and `interchanges` report this as nothing to do:

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 interchanges bar foo
bar - all revision(s) already integrated.

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 integ bar foo
bar - all revision(s) already integrated.
```

This is thanks to the `undo/undone` credits that you can see in the filelog.  `integrate` can see that #3 is just the inverse of #2, so it adds them together and finds nothing to do.

Now suppose I add another edit and do a "fake undo" (this is what happens if you e.g. roll back a change with an old script or version of P4V that doesn't know about `p4 undo`):

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 edit bar
//stream/test2/undo/bar#3 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test\undo>echo asdfasdf >> bar

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 submit -d edit
Submitting change 251.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/test2/undo/bar#4
Change 251 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 sync bar#3
//stream/test2/undo/bar#3 - updating c:\Perforce\test\undo\bar

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 edit bar
//stream/test2/undo/bar#3 - opened for edit
... //stream/test2/undo/bar - must sync/resolve #4 before submitting

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 sync bar
//stream/test2/undo/bar#4 - is opened and not being changed
... //stream/test2/undo/bar - must resolve #4 before submitting

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 resolve -ay
c:\Perforce\test\undo\bar - vs //stream/test2/undo/bar#4
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/undo/bar - ignored //stream/test2/undo/bar

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 submit -d "fake undo"
Submitting change 252.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/test2/undo/bar#5
Change 252 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 integ -n bar foo
//stream/test2/undo/foo#1 - integrate from //stream/test2/undo/bar#2,#5

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 interchanges bar foo
Change 251 on 2021/06/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 'edit'
Change 252 on 2021/06/25 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 'fake undo'
```

What if I want to fix this after the fact?  You mentioned that the stream was already copied up -- with a normal copy, there is no metadata record of this if the files were already identical (due to some sort of tricky operation like this).  That is, even though `integrate` sees outstanding revisions, `copy` says "up-to-date":

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 copy -n bar foo
File(s) up-to-date.
```

In most situations this doesn't matter because you don't copy and merge in the same direction, and so `copy` biases toward not creating extra revisions for no good reason.  In the event you *do* want the records to be updated so that `copy` and `integrate` agree with each other, though, you can do a copy with the `-f` flag, which tells it to create new revisions for the sole purpose of integration credit:

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 copy -f bar foo
//stream/test2/undo/foo#1 - sync/integrate from //stream/test2/undo/bar#2,#5

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 submit -d "recordkeeping copy"
Submitting change 253.
Locking 1 files ...
integrate //stream/test2/undo/foo#2
Change 253 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 interchanges bar foo
bar - all revision(s) already integrated.
```

The `copy -f` operation will still do nothing if the files are identical *and* the credit is fully up to date:

```
C:\Perforce\test\undo>p4 copy -f bar foo
File(s) up-to-date.
```

so it's safe to use in non-edge cases as well.

Now, if you don't have any control over any of this, and you just want your script to not report changelists when the two streams are identical *by content* even if they aren't fully up to date *by credit*: do `p4 copy -n` before you do `p4 interchanges`, and if it reports "up to date", then for your purposes you can just treat it as `p4 interchanges` reporting the same thing.